# Assign select value to variable in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table:

**Example**:

```
create table test
( 
 id int,
 name varchar(10),
 city varchar(10)
);
```

I want to assign ID value from table to variable in the function.

Function:

```
create or replace function testing(ids int,names varchar(10),citys varchar(10)
returns void as
$body$
Declare
       ident int;
BEGIN
       ident := SELECT ID FROM test;
       raise info '%',ident;
END;
$body$
Language plpgsql;
```

**Error Details**:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 12:  ident := SELECT ID from test;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `select ... into`

```
create or replace function testing(ids int,names varchar(10),citys varchar(10)
returns void as
$body$
Declare
       ident int;
       foo   text;
BEGIN
       SELECT ID, some_col  
          into ident, foo 
       FROM test;
       raise info '%',ident;
END;
$body$
Language plpgsql;
```

More details and examples are in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Comment: What if I want to assign multiple values to multiple variables?

Comment: As stated in the manual: "*where target can be a record variable, a row variable, or a comma-separated list of simple variables and record/row fields*" See my edit